# Ya se agregó un elemento con la misma clave

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model, model-view-controller

Estoy utilizando Code first MVC 2017 con sql Server 2014
Tengo un modelo llamado PADRON
tengo un VieWModels llamado PADRONVM
dos tablas una llamada SEXO y otra llamada COLONIA
Hice un ViewModels pero no se donde pueda estar el error

De antemano gracias.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MMC.Models
{
    [Table("PADRON")]
    public class PADRON
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdPadron { get; set; }
        public string Clave_Elector { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido_Paterno { get; set; }
        public string Apellido_Materno { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public int IdSexo { get; set; }
        //public string IdCodPostal { get; set; }
        //public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public int IdColonia { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MMC.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MMC.ViewModels
{
    public partial class PADRONVM
    {
        public int Id_Padron { get; set; }
        public string Clave_Elector { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido_Paterno { get; set; }
        public string Apellido_Materno { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }

        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Colonia { get; set; }

        public PADRON padron { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SEXO> sexo { get; set; }
        public int Id_Sexo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<COLONIA> colonia { get; set; }
        public int Id_Colonia { get; set; }
    }
}


public ActionResult Agregar()
{
   var Sex = db.SEXO.ToList();
   var col = db.COLONIAS.ToList();
   var viewmodels = new PADRONVM
   {
      sexo = Sex,
      colonia = col
   };
   return View(viewmodels);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Agregar(PADRONVM model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {           
      var padron = new PADRON();
      {
         padron.Clave_Elector = model.Clave_Elector;
         padron.Nombre = model.Nombre;
         padron.Apellido_Paterno = model.Apellido_Paterno;
         padron.Apellido_Materno = model.Apellido_Materno;
         padron.Edad = model.Edad;
         padron.Direccion = model.Direccion;
         padron.IdSexo = model.Id_Sexo;
         padron.IdColonia = model.Id_Sexo;
      }
      db.PADRON.Add(padron);
      db.SaveChanges();               
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   else
   {
      model.sexo = db.SEXO.ToList();
      model.colonia = db.COLONIAS.ToList();
      return View(model);
   }
}

@model IEnumerable<MMC.ViewModels.PADRONVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>aaa</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Agregar")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Clave_Elector</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
        <th>Edad</th>
        <th>Direccion</th>
        <th>Sexo</th>
        <th>Colonia</th>
        <th>Accion</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clave_Elector)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido_Paterno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido_Materno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Edad)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Direccion)
            </td>
            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sexo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Colonia)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id_Padron }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id_Padron }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id_Padron })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. Ya se agregó un elemento con
> la misma clave. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la
> solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener
> más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
> 
> Detalles de la excepción: System.ArgumentException: Ya se agregó un
> elemento con la misma clave.
> 
> Error de código fuente: Se  ha generado una excepción no controlada
> durante la ejecución de la solicitud Web actual. La información sobre
> el origen y la ubicación de la excepción pueden identificarse
> utilizando la excepción del seguimiento de la pila siguiente.
> 
> Seguimiento de la pila: [ArgumentException: Ya se agregó un elemento
> con la misma clave.]   
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
> +56    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +12948692   
> System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.ToDictionaryFast(TValue[]
> array, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +116   
> System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext.get_PropertyMetadata() +136   
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
> PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +176   
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +101   
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
> +55    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1197   
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330   
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +338   
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback
> asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +14   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
> state) +343   
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback
> asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +30   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128   
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
> Object state) +465   
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback
> asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +20   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128   
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
> AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374   
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
> requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16   
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback
> asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52 
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object callbackState) +30   
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128   
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384   
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
> AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48   
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16   
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +105    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
> 
> Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319;
> Versión ASP.NET:4.8.4250.0
```

Comment: Creaste un id autoincremental en tus tablas de BD?

Comment: Hola Paulo, gracias por apoyarme.. Si tengo en mi BD como Autoincremental el Id de la clave principal en cada tabla. veo que mi problema esta en cuando quito las variables Sexo y Colonia me genera el grid pero me lo cicla y me repite los datos, ademas me permite entrar a a la vista agregar campos, pero no me los guarda :(